# Bitcoin Chainstate Leveldb sst

Tags: blockchain, development, leveldb

I'm trying to read the chainstate, and wrote a small Leveldb client to do so.  When I run leveldb, it tells me `Corruption: 960 missing files; e.g.: /opt/bitcoin/chainstate/890787.sst`.  Googling shows that Leveldb uses `.sst` files, but, I don't see a single one on my machine.

How do I generate these files / repair the chainstate leveldb / access it from a leveldb client?

Comment: Is Bitcoin Core already running?

Answer (score 1):

the default extension is now ldb https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leveldb/u9izbG-pDis

Which library are you using to read leveldb? I suggest you use [plyvel](https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It will be able to read chainstate